# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

**Apache Maven:** 3.8.1
**Java version:** 1.8.0_311

Getting the below error while running the maven command in Jenkins pipeline.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project gehc-de-qa-automation: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
```

The same command works perfectly fine in my local windows laptop but not in Jenkins pipeline running on Linux.

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>boo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>fooboo</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>2.6.0</serenity.version>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.29</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-alpha10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.sukgu</groupId>
            <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Command used:**

```
mvn -X clean install
mvn -X clean install -U
```

**Error:**

```
20:05:24  [DEBUG] Using mirror artifactory (https://hc-eu-west-aws-artifactory.cloud.health.ge.com/artifactory/list/maven-ext-all/) for central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).
20:05:24  [DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M5:
20:05:24  [DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:3.0.0-M5:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:3.0.0-M5:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-logger-api:jar:3.0.0-M5:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-extensions-api:jar:3.0.0-M5:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:3.0.0-M5:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-extensions-spi:jar:3.0.0-M5:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:3.0-alpha-2:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.shared:maven-artifact-transfer:jar:0.11.0:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:3.1.0:compile (version managed from 3.0.1)
20:05:24  [DEBUG]             org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]          commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-java:jar:1.0.5:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]          org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.2:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]          com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:2.0-M9:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-shared-utils:jar:3.0.0-M4:compile
20:05:24  [DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1:runtime
20:05:24  [DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5
20:05:24  [DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
20:05:24  [DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:3.0.0-M5
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:3.0.0-M5
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:3.0.0-M5
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-logger-api:jar:3.0.0-M5
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-extensions-api:jar:3.0.0-M5
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:3.0.0-M5
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-extensions-spi:jar:3.0.0-M5
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-artifact-transfer:jar:0.11.0
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:3.1.0
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-java:jar:1.0.5
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:7.2
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:2.0-M9
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-shared-utils:jar:3.0.0-M4
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:3.0-alpha-2
20:05:24  [DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0
20:05:24  [DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1b9e1916]
20:05:24  May 04, 2022 8:07:53 PM org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.Logs$JULSink warn
20:05:24  WARNING: Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
20:05:24  com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
20:05:24  
20:05:24  1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
20:05:24    while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
20:05:24  
20:05:24  1 error
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
20:05:24    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
20:05:24    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:138)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
20:05:24    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
20:05:24    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:253)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:245)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:455)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
20:05:24    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
20:05:24    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
20:05:24    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
20:05:24    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
20:05:24  
20:05:24  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:05:24  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
20:05:24  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:05:24  [INFO] Total time: 21.497s
20:05:24  [INFO] Finished at: Wed May 04 20:07:53 IST 2022
20:05:24  [INFO] Final Memory: 57M/192M
20:05:24  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
20:05:24  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project abcd-foo: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5': com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
20:05:24  [ERROR] 
20:05:24  [ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
20:05:24  [ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
20:05:24  [ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1b9e1916]
20:05:24  [ERROR] while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test)
20:05:24  [ERROR] 
20:05:24  [ERROR] 1 error
20:05:24  [ERROR] role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
20:05:24  [ERROR] roleHint: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test
20:05:24  [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
20:05:24  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project abcd-foo: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5'
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
20:05:24    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
20:05:24    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
20:05:24    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
20:05:24    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:414)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:357)
20:05:24  Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test failed: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5'
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:115)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
20:05:24    ... 19 more
20:05:24  Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5'
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:488)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
20:05:24    ... 20 more
20:05:24  Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
20:05:24  
20:05:24  1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
20:05:24    while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
20:05:24    at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1b9e1916]
20:05:24    while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test)
20:05:24  
20:05:24  1 error
20:05:24        role: org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
20:05:24    roleHint: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:257)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:245)
20:05:24    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:455)
20:05:24    ... 21 more
20:05:24  Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
20:05:24  
20:05:24  1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
20:05:24    while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
20:05:24    at ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1b9e1916]
20:05:24    while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test)
20:05:24  
20:05:24  1 error
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
20:05:24    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
20:05:24    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
20:05:24    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
20:05:24    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:253)
20:05:24    ... 23 more
20:05:24  [ERROR] 
20:05:24  [ERROR] 
20:05:24  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
20:05:24  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // gitlabCommitStatus
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // gitlabCommitStatus
[Pipeline] echo
20:05:27  finally block...
[Pipeline] echo
20:05:27   Build Failure:script returned exit code 1 
[Pipeline] echo
20:05:27  [CTTDSLLIB] Posting to http://es-digitaldashboard.cloud.health.ge.com/elastic/events/ with body {"created":1651674927589,"product":"devopsms","jobURL":"http://de-jenkins.eng.med.ge.com/job/boo/job/QA-Automation/job/abcd-foo/job/jenkins-changes/15/","org":"Imaging","team":"devopsms","branch":"jenkins-changes","jobName":"boo/QA-Automation/abcd-foo/jenkins-changes","component":"abcd-foo","release":"1.0.0","eventTimestamp":"2022-05-04T20:04:05.922Z","createdBy":"jaas","status":"FAILURE","pipelinePhase":"TEST","elapsedTime":81659,"description":"job level FAILURE","project":null,"source":"jaas","program":"Imaging"}
[Pipeline] echo
20:05:28  [CTTDSLLIB] POST got response to with code 201 Response: Created
[Pipeline] echo
20:05:30  project parameters for testing
[Pipeline] echo
20:05:30  abcd-foo
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Notify)
[Pipeline] gitlabCommitStatus
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] updateGitlabCommitStatus
[Pipeline] echo
20:05:32  notify [start]
[Pipeline] node
20:05:32  Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/de-qa-automation_jenkins-changes
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] dir
20:05:32  Running in /var/jenkins_home/jaas_workspace/jenkins-boo-QA-Automation-abcd-foo-jenkins-changes-15.jaas_email_attachment
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] echo
20:05:33  [CTTDSLLIB FINE]No attachement directory found : /var/jenkins_home/jaas_workspace/jenkins-boo-QA-Automation-abcd-foo-jenkins-changes-15.jaas_email_attachment 
[Pipeline] echo
20:05:33  [CTTDSLLIB FINE]Attaching 0 attachments 
[Pipeline] emailext
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] dir
20:05:45  Running in /var/jenkins_home/jaas_workspace/jenkins-boo-QA-Automation-abcd-foo-jenkins-changes-15.jaas_email_attachment
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] dir
20:05:45  Running in /var/jenkins_home/jaas_workspace/jenkins-boo-QA-Automation-abcd-foo-jenkins-changes-15.jaas_email_attachment@tmp
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] echo
20:05:45  notify [end]
[Pipeline] updateGitlabCommitStatus
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // gitlabCommitStatus
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] cleanWs
20:05:47  [WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...
20:05:47  [WS-CLEANUP] Deferred wipeout is used...
20:05:47  [WS-CLEANUP] done
[Pipeline] echo
20:05:47  common_pipeline [end]
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // ansiColor
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
[GitLab Pipeline Status] Notifying branch build status: FAILED boo/QA-Automation/abcd-foo/jenkins-changes: There was a failure building this commit
[GitLab Pipeline Status] Notified
Finished: FAILURE
```

Could someone assist as to what could be the reason for the failure in pipeline?

Comment: Please show the output of `mvn --version` on your CI system (Jenkins)

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade both plugins to 3.0.0-M6.